# Error while trying to store image as byte array using SubSonic

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, subsonic

Does SubSonic provide any mechanism  to store image (converted in byte[] format)? 
Can someone help to get rid of this error?

Database : SQL server 2005
Developing enviornment: ASP.NET (c#)
Subsonic version:2.2.1.0

Datatype in DB: image
Datatype in Subsonic generated DAL : DbType.Binary
datatype in code: byte[] image

Error at statement:

```
DB.Insert().Into(DamageItems.Schema, "ImageID", "Cost","Image").Values(imageID, cost,image).Execute();
```

Query Expression in watch window:

```
{INSERT INTO [dbo].[ImageItems](ImageID,Cost,Image)
 VALUES (@ins_ImageID,@ins_Cost,@ins_Image)
}
```

Error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a String.

Comment: Hoe come it's `DamageItems` in the insert statement, but `ImageItems` in the watch window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following approach:

```
DB.Insert().Into<DamageItems>()
    .Value(DamageItems.ImageIDColumn, imageID)
    .Value(DamageItems.CostColumn, cost)
    .Value(DamageItems.ImageColumn, image)
    .Execute();
```

Maybe the type gets properly recognized when specifying `TableColumn` objects (can't test right now while writing this).

If that doesn't work, I'd also check whether naming a column with a data type name (`image`) causes any problem.

By the way, from SQL 2005 on, `image` is deprecated, it is recommended to use `varbinary(max)` instead.

Comment: sorry forgot mentione more details. I am using RepositoryRecord not activeRecord. SO when I use method DB.Inser().Into<DamageItems>(), I get error as : 
" The type 'Damages.DAL.DamageItems' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SubSonic.Insert.Into<T>(params string[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Damages.DAL.DamageItems' to 'SubSonic.ActiveRecord<Damages.DAL.DamageItems>'." Do subsonic have function to take care of it using RepositoryRecord.

Comment: I tried varbinary(max) as db type before using image, but had same error. Also tried changing datatype name, didn't work.

Comment: I used DB.Save(this); to store, and it worked. (I kept image as varbinary(MAX), in subsonic generated class it comes as DbType.Binary and in my code I passed image data as byte[]) . Anyway thanks to Marapet (http://stackoverflow.com/users/63733/marapet), but that method was for active records where as I am using Repository records.